# Tracking Real-Time Visitors on a URL

Tags: real-time, google-analytics-api

Google Analytics provides 'real-time' active visitor count for specific pages/urls. I don't think they expose that through the API. Is anyone aware of a tool that I can use to keep track of real-time active visitors for specific pages on my site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Now, Google has launched new API- Google Real Time API, which provides this facility. with this you can extract similar data.

try : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/devguide